# uglification of echarts.js library is very slow, possibly because of presence of chinese characters

Tags: javascript, encoding, gulp

A bit of a specific question, I'm currently running a server side application that uses the echarts js library. And I've noticed that the uglification of the echarts file is taking very long. In the order of multiple minutes rather than milliseconds and seconds. Echarts is quite a large file, but it is still disproportionately slow, so I've come to the educated guess that it may be the presence of **chinese** characters in the library.

This uglification process is taking place inside of a gulp streaming task.

Does anybody know of a way to reduce the time for the uglification of chinese characters?

Answer (score 0):

[fixed] 
This issue was due to the fact that the file path I was pointing to as a source for my uglification process pointed to a file that was already uglified 
... oops :)

Reduced my build time by a factor of 5